# running umount on HFS filesystem gets stuck in D state, preventing suspend to RAM

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, suspend, hfs+

I have mounted an HFS file system from a disk image and proceeded to `umount` it. upon doing so, the `umount` process entered `D` state and did not leave. the filesystem is unmounted, but the process remains in `D` state.

now that it is in `D` state, I am completely unable to suspend my system to RAM.

a solution to this problem would either be to find a way to suspend regardless of the `D` state process or to find a way to take the process out of `D` state.

dmesg says:

```
[3157428.258176] INFO: task umount:2459 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[3157428.258177]       Tainted: G           OE     4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.181-1
[3157428.258178] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[3157428.258179] umount          D    0  2459   2458 0x00000000
[3157428.258180] Call Trace:
[3157428.258181]  __schedule+0x29f/0x840
[3157428.258182]  ? bit_wait_timeout+0x90/0x90
[3157428.258183]  schedule+0x28/0x80
[3157428.258184]  io_schedule+0x12/0x40
[3157428.258185]  bit_wait_io+0xd/0x50
[3157428.258186]  __wait_on_bit_lock+0x5d/0xa0
[3157428.258187]  out_of_line_wait_on_bit_lock+0x91/0xb0
[3157428.258189]  ? init_wait_var_entry+0x40/0x40
[3157428.258191]  hfs_mdb_commit+0x326/0x340 [hfs]
[3157428.258192]  hfs_sync_fs+0xa/0x10 [hfs]
[3157428.258195]  __sync_filesystem+0x2c/0x50
[3157428.258196]  sync_filesystem+0x2a/0x40
[3157428.258198]  generic_shutdown_super+0x22/0x100
[3157428.258199]  kill_block_super+0x21/0x50
[3157428.258201]  deactivate_locked_super+0x2f/0x70
[3157428.258203]  cleanup_mnt+0x3f/0x70
[3157428.258205]  task_work_run+0x8a/0xb0
[3157428.258208]  exit_to_usermode_loop+0xeb/0xf0
[3157428.258210]  do_syscall_64+0x10d/0x110
[3157428.258211]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
```

Comment: It's generally a bug. It could also be some process either has a file or directory open within the file system, or perhaps some processes current working directory is within it and thus cannot be unmounted as it is busy, although umount should tell you this. If you cannot find those, you are going to have to force a shutdown. Regardless, ensure you have the latest updates and if it happens again, let either your distro know or the KML.

Comment: it cannot be that the mountpoint is busy, because it unmounts. `umount` remains in `D` state regardless. I will edit the question to add this detail.